CUDA Out of Memory Error when Chunking Audio and Running Whisper Transcription in Python
I'm working on a Python script that transcribes audio files using a library that leverages CUDA for GPU acceleration. The transcription process involves chunking the audio file into smaller segments and then running the transcription on each chunk.The issue only arises when I try to process the chunked audios iteratively.
Here's a simplified version of the code:
import torch
from pydub import AudioSegment

def process_audio_file(audio_file, sample_path, chunk_duration=1800000):  # Chunk duration in milliseconds (30 mins)
    audio = AudioSegment.from_mp3(audio_file)

    combined_output = []
    start = 0
    end = chunk_duration

    while end <= len(audio):
        chunk = audio[start:end]
        silence_chunks = split_audio_into_chunks(chunk, min_silence_len=1000, silence_thresh=-40)

        for sub_chunk in silence_chunks:
            temp_file = f"chunk.mp3"
            sub_chunk.export(temp_file, format="mp3")

            # Call transcription function on the temporary file
            chunk_output = run_transcription(temp_file, sample_path)

            combined_output.extend(chunk_output)
            os.remove(temp_file)

            # Release CUDA memory
            torch.cuda.empty_cache()

        start += len(chunk)
        end = start + chunk_duration

    # ... (remaining code)

The problem I'm facing is that after the first or second iteration of the for loop, where I call the run_transcription function I get a single word on the terminal saying "Killed" and my script stops.
I have checked CUDA memory before and after each iteration and it is not being properly released, and it accumulates until it exceeds the available memory.
I've tried calling torch.cuda.empty_cache() after each iteration to release the CUDA memory, but the issue persists.
My questions are:
Why is the CUDA memory not being properly released after each iteration, even though I'm calling torch.cuda.empty_cache()?
Is there a better way to handle CUDA memory management when chunking audio and running transcription on each chunk?
Are there any other potential causes for the CUDA out of memory error in this scenario?
Additional Information:
I'm using Python 3.9 on a system with an NVIDIA RTX 3060 GPU with 6 GB of CUDA memory.
The audio files I'm processing are typically around 1-2 hours long chunked into 30 mins( so around 4-5 iterations).
The run_transcription function utilizes a library that leverages CUDA for GPU acceleration, but I don't have control over its internal implementation.
Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if you need any additional information or code samples.
